# Column that counts based on another one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'transaction_id':[12565,12565,12743,12743,13456,13456,13856],
                'rep_id':[560,560,560,560,287,287,287]})
```

I want to create a new column with a counter like below.

```
       transaction_id   rep_id  trans_num
    0           12565      560          1
    1           12565      560          1
    2           12743      560          2
    3           12743      560          2
    4           13456      287          1
    5           13456      287          1
    6           13856      287          2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with `transform` + `factorize`

```
df['new']=df.groupby('rep_id').transaction_id.transform(lambda x : pd.factorize(x)[0]+1)
df
Out[389]: 
   transaction_id  rep_id  new
0           12565     560    1
1           12565     560    1
2           12743     560    2
3           12743     560    2
4           13456     287    1
5           13456     287    1
6           13856     287    2
```

Comment: maybe also`df.groupby('rep_id')['transaction_id'].transform(lambda x: x.astype('category').cat.codes+1)` could work

Comment: @wwnde some time the category will return the un-order codes ~ :-)

Comment: @BENY, I suspected so hence the use of maybe. Will leave my comment for purposes of firming up the knowledge and dispelling the desire to think that is an alternative to `pd.factorize`. Good answer

Comment: @wwnde imho, `astype('category')` will be a bit slower than `factorize` as it needs to do some bookkeeping, while `factorize` returns the numy arrays straight up. I even saw `factorize` faster than `np.unique`. That said, I usually try to avoid `apply/transform` with a lambda function. Good answer still though.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your data (`transaction_id` are different if `rep_id` are different)  we can also do:

```
df['new'] = (df['transaction_id'].ne(df['transaction_id'].shift())
    .groupby(df['rep_id']).cumsum()
)
```

**Update**: You can also use `rank`, although it behaves a bit differently:

```
df.groupby('rep_id')['transaction_id'].rank('dense').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   transaction_id  rep_id  new
0           12565     560    1
1           12565     560    1
2           12743     560    2
3           12743     560    2
4           13456     287    1
5           13456     287    1
6           13856     287    2
```

Comment: A different rep_id can have the same transaction_id.

Comment: @excelater I see, updated the answer with a different approach.